# ASP.NET resolve symbol dataset in App_Code folder

Tags: asp.net

I have a project where some datasets with table adapters are stored in the App_Code folder in VS 2010. I am unable to get access to the table adapters from code behind. I tried following [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/15/435498.aspx) guide that was written for VS 2005, however, VS 2010 says it cannot resolve symbol. Is there any additional namespaces I need to add for VS 2010 to resolve the symbol?

My code is similar to the following, but with the correct names of the dataset and table adapter.

var tableAdapter = new NorthwindTableAdapters.SuppliersTableAdapter();

Comment: What namespace is your dataset in?

Comment: The project is a web site project and not a web application project so I do not see any namespaces unless one is generated internally.

Comment: Please consider this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31557/A-Beginner-s-Guide-to-ASP-NET-Application-Folders

Comment: Could you post the code you've put in your class file in the `App_Code` folder as well please? =]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your responses. Problem turned out to be a problem in porting the project from VS 2008 to VS 2010.